# Get Latitude / Longitude from Address with Accuracy

Tags: google-maps, maps, latitude-longitude

I know this question has been asked too many times but my question is more of about standard approach.

I do have following fields in my form and using all of them for concatenation and sending to the Google Maps Api for fetching address which works.

But for some address Google Maps Api gives wrong lat/long due to the values insertion. fields with values are mentioned below.

**Fields :**

**Street Address 1**  - SHOP NO 56

**Location** -  Sector 14

**State** -  Haryana

**City** -  Gurgaon

Resulting Google Map Url is giving me Lat/long of Sector 56 rather than Sector 14. Almost 9 Kms Difference.

http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=Shop+No+56,Sector+14,Haryana,Gurgaon,IN

Can anybody please help me in this ?

**What I tried/thought**

I was planning to use Only Location Field but I suspect that will not help much.

Comment: That sounds like a "place", you might investigate using the Places API to retrieve its location.

Comment: Thanks for the direction and your answer GeocodeZip :)  I am not sure why negative votes on my question.. thanks again for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's true, businesses are excluded from Geocoding API. If you need a location for certain business just use the Places API.

E.g. 
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/textsearch/json?query=Shop%20No%2056%2C%20Sector%2014%2C%20Haryana%2C%20Gurgaon%2C%20IN&key=YOUR_API_KEY